# Running instances of a particular class on network (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

So, I have a class *SomeCode.py* (daemon) running on multiple hosts in my network.
I need to scan the network and find the number of running instances of the class.

I am working on Windows10

EDIT 1:
Sample content for SomeCode.py

```
import time
class SomeCode(object):
    def something(self):
        while(True):
           time.sleep(10)
           print("SomeCode Running")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = SomeCode()
    obj.something()
```

I have already tried this:

```
import gc
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, MyClass):
        print obj.name
```

Brute Force approach - Works for my PC but how to implement on network

Comment: what you are exactly doing? what `backend.py` does?

Comment: Pro-tip: a script that prints that the back end is running, is not an actual network back end to anything.

Comment: @Grismar  I am not interested in what that file does.. You can call it ''DoesNothing.py" but if its running on 10 PCs in network , I need to count of running instances

Comment: Without telling people what OS it is running on, or how it actually provides a service on the network, that's not really a valid question. People won't be very "interested" in helping you if you drop poorly written questions that show little to no effort to finding an answer yourself.

Comment: Its Windows 10 PC, Sorry did not know that would affect.. Really a noob..

Answer (score 1):

@vidya marathe:You can use Python Socket programming to achieve this...one machine run code that acts as a socket server and remaining clients will connect over socket to this server and can emit events after successful deployment...

1)Run Socket server
2)Create 10 socket clients that will connect to socket server
3)Send event to socket server after execution of your calls...etc

refer below:
https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: Not really the solution.. I already have an implemented/existing class running on multiple PCs, in the network. I need to count the running instances at some point in time... just need the number of instances running..

Comment: Yes,Same environment you add socket server and client mechanism to it....